# showing custom component in header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

On one screen, I would like to have a custom component to be shown on the header.

I tried:

```
 const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: props => {
      <MyComponent {...props} />;
    },
  });

  ...
 export default MyScreen;
```

But it shows blank like below:

[image]

To further verify the approach is correct, I also tried to simply show a text:

```
navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: props => {
      <Text {...props}> Hello </Text>;
    },
  });
```

It also shows blank in the header title area. What am I missing? How to show a custom component in the header?

(`MyScreen` is hosted by a stack navigator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not returning the component, hence why it is not displayed.

You should either write:

```js
const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: props => {
      return <MyComponent {...props} />;
    },
  });
}, [navigation]);
  ...
export default MyScreen;
```

or for a more concise syntax:

```js
const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: props => <MyComponent {...props} />,
  });
}, [navigation]);
  ...
export default MyScreen;
```

You also need to use `useLayoutEffect` because you cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
`useLayoutEffect` runs synchronously after a render but before the screen is visually updated, which will prevent your screen to flicker when your title is displayed.

By the way, since you seemingly don't need to use a function as props of your component, you could define this option directly in your navigator like so:

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="MyScreen"
    component={MyScreen}
    options={{ headerTitle: props => <MyComponent {...props} /> }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```